# Ubuntu 12.04 c++ development system install

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, c++

I am trying to install the Intel Parallel Studio 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04.  During installation I received a failure notice that the command g++ was missing.  I asked Intel and they indicated that the C++ development system needs to be installed.  Can I install this without having to go through the install again?

Answer (score 4):

On a Ubuntu system, you can install the c++ compiler along with common development libraries with the [`build-essential`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/build-essential) package. This is a meta package that depends on the following:

```
libc6-dev | libc-dev, gcc, g++, make, dpkg-dev
```

This is the base of what is needed for compiling `C` and `C++`. Other development libraries can be installed as-needed.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate you assistance in locating the build-essential package.  I've already spent quite alot of time looking through the different directories as well as on the internet.  Also, how do I go about ensuring the second line is true, libc6-dev ...

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem, you can install the build-essential package by using the following command in the terminal: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: @Arnold you should have a package manager somewhere in your Ubuntu menus, which you can use to install packages. Forget exactly what it's called. It'll also let you browse & search the available packages (there are a lot)

Comment: @derobert "Software Center" on modern Ubuntu, "Synaptic Package Manager" on older versions (and Debian).